# algorithm2e: How to define my own macros? +2

Tags: algorithm2e

Just starting to play around with the `algorithm2e` package and I have difficulties to figure out the things I need.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[lined,boxed,commentsnumbered,german]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\ForAll{$i\in \left[n\right]$ in parallel}{
    $a\leftarrow b$\;
}    
\textbf{repeat} $\left\lceil\log n \right\rceil$ \textbf{times}\;\Indp{
\If{$b > 1$}{
    $b\leftarrow c$
}}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

which gives me this:
[image: Example]

1. Instead of '**forall the**' I would prefer to have just '**for all**'. Instead of '*in parallel* **do**' I would prefer to have it together as '**in parallel do**'. How do I achieve that?
2. How do I define my own macro '**repeat**', so that is has an 'end'-statement, 'times' is inserted and a working vertical line at the left border?
3. Is it possible to remove the 'end' of the 'if'-statement? 'lIf' is neat, but not really what I am looking for..

I tried to understand the [documentation](http://mirror.unicorncloud.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) and the threads here on stackexchange, but the examples are quite complicated for a beginner, so I would be grateful for any advice.

Thanks in advance!

[not a native english speaker]

Comment: `\SetKwFor{ForAll}{for all}{do}{end forall}` for the first question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first version, not complete so far!

The `\SetKwX` macros define much of the keywords and appearance style, but not all is possible, apparently, without manual interaction on the precise position when the `\ForAll` etc. statements are used.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[lined,boxed,commentsnumbered,german]{algorithm2e}

\SetKwFor{ForAll}{for all}{do}{end}
\SetKwRepeat{Repeat}{repeat}{end}
%\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{then}{else if}{else}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\ForAll{$i\in \left[n\right]$ in parallel}{
    $a\leftarrow b$\;
}    
\Repeat($\left\lceil\log n \right\rceil$ times){}{%
  \lIf{$b > 1$}{\\
    $b\leftarrow c$
  }
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, these answered most of my questions. Together with '\Indp{' it should definitely work.

Comment: @CurryCurry: Apparently I missed `\lndp` -- well, if it fits you needs, you can consider to accept it later on